# Changing permissions on serial port

Tags: permissions, chmod, serial-port, arduino

I'm using the Arduino IDE in Ubuntu, and am having issues with the serial port. It has worked in the past, but for reasons that may be unnecesary, I felt the need to change the ownership of some of the files from root ownership to my users ownership.

This made the IDE work correctly, but I lost the ability to use the correct serial port.  In the dev folder, the port I need is listed as permission 166. Someone (who is no longer in the area to help me) swapped the permissions to 666, which made it all work gloriously.

However, it reverted back as soon as I restarted my computer, and if I now try to use the command:

```
sudo chmod 666 ttyACM0
```

nothing happens. No error messages, but no permission change either.

How can I change it, and how can I get it to change permanently.

I apologize if this question is overly simplistic or unclear, I'm an ubuntu noob, and I wouldn't begrudge feedback!

Comment: sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0 This was the only suggestion on this page that worked on my 14.04 beta2 live environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The issue with the permissions for `/dev/ttyACM0` can be permanantly solved by adding yourself to the `dialout` group.

You can do this with:

1. `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER`
2. Logout and then log back in for the group changes to take effect.

Comment: I learnt about this when Arduino IDE asked to give to root to add itself to the "Dailout group". Now I know what it is.

Comment: I just purchased a Pulse-Eight USB - CEC Adapter for use with my new TV and found that it did not initially work with Kodi in Ubuntu. After checking the crash-log and googling the error message "ERROR: CecLogMessage - error opening serial port '/dev/ttyACM0': Permission denied", this page came up as a result. Thanks to you (and Don Kirkby, below - that works, too), I was able to rectify the problem immediately.

Comment: Also, the answer from "user247020" gave me another solution: Open the GUI tool "Users and Groups" and make yourself an "Administrator". This will add you to the "dialout" group (ie. "Use Modems"), amongst others.

Comment: usermod -a -G dialout pi works ok, after sudo chgrp dialout /dev/ttyS0 and work well but when i reboot all the config is lost. I'm on raspberry pi 3

Comment: Add any command you need to redo to a startup script. So bash or /etc/profile or init.

Comment: Note that *logout* means "log out of X session", not just "open new X terminal". Took me some time to figure that out.

Comment: To the anon user editing: I rejected it. A chmod in /dev/  gets overwritten during a reboot.

Comment: This didn't worked for me in Xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Why not? it is a generic solution.  We all have a "dialout" user and the device is owned by "dialout".

Answer (score 21):

I couldn't get [Rinzwind's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/58122/3986) to work, because it complained that the user account already exists. Instead, I used this command to add an existing user (`terrik`) to an existing group (`dialout`), as described on the [Ubuntu Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto#Command-line).

```
sudo adduser terrik dialout
```

Also useful is this command for listing your current groups, although as Rinzwind says, you have to log out and log in before the serial port starts letting you in.

```
groups terrik
```

Answer (score 16):

Another possibility is to make a rules file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory. I had similar problem and I have created `50-myusb.rules` file in the above directory with this content:

```
KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*",MODE="0666"
```

Note that this will give any device connected to ttyACM socket read/write permissions. If you need only specific device to get read/write permissions you must also check `idVendor` and `idProduct`. You can find those by running `lsusb` command twice, once without your device connected and once when it is connected, then observe the additional line in the output. There you will see something like `Bus 003 Device 005: ID ffff:0005`. In this case `idVendor = ffff` and `idProduct = 0005`. Yours will be different. Than you modify the rules  file to:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="ffff", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0005", MODE="0666"
```

Now only this device gets the permissions. [Read this](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) to know more about writing udev rules.

Answer (score 12):

I couldn't get [Terrik's answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/58119/154670) working, but I could if I made this slight adjustment to the path for `ttyACM0`.

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Would post as a comment but I don't have the privileges for that yet...

Comment: The permissions seem to reset when unplugging and replugging Arduino back in.

Comment: does not work. :(

Comment: it works , well as well. but requires udev rule to re-permit on repplugging

Comment: I tried `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0` and it doesn't work when starting up again.  Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Hmm peepz this does work .... Add the command to a startup script. (/Dev gets recreated on boot so you need to redo this command each boot)

Comment: My 2 cents: I decided I rather enjoy the behaviour of permissions resetting after unplugging/rebooting. I'm not sure what the security implications are for being in the dialout group unnecessarily, but I think it's a good idea to keep serial-and-other external communications as a root-only privilege if possible. It's easy enough to just reset permission back to 0666 when you're ready to flash, unless you're doing a lot of unplugging and replugging. /paranoid

Comment: Add the following two lines to the end of your ~/.bashrc

**# Give permissions to serial port used by Arduino IDE**
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0

Answer (score 2):

Try going into System / Users and Groups and checkeing the box on your username in the TTY Group.

Comment: `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyACM0'`.  As well as `tty` group, user is also in `dialout` group. Linux Mint 17.1.

Comment: @user1063287 Try `sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0`