# How to grant file permission in /dev directory permanently?

Tags: permissions, udev, serial-port

I have a file `/dev/ttyS0`. And every time I boot, its file permissions are changed to default (unwritable) by the system. So, I have to run a `chmod` command every time I boot-up. How can I change its file permission permanently?

Comment: What does it means "unwritable by the system"? Please show the output of `ls -l /dev/ttyS0`.

Comment: Why does this down vote? we use linux, isn't that mean we have freedom to set what chmod we want.

Comment: @enzotib Every time reboot, the chmod back to 660

Comment: Here may answer you question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58119/changing-permissions-on-serial-port

Comment: @GusDeCooL - Sure do what you want. Best thing abut open source, if you break it you get to keep both pieces.

Comment: suba - what did you do to get into this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the file permission is not a good idea. I think /dev/ttyS* are designed to be accessed by user space applications, so you dont need to make it accessible to everybody. Instead you should give permission to use the serial ports to users that need access. If I am not wrong, you can do this by adding your user to the group **uucp** which can be done by running the following command in the terminal:

```
usermod -aG uucp <you_user_name>
```

If this does not solve your issue, try posting a bit more details on what you are doing. What device are you accessing and explaining how are you writing to it, and perhaps providing some code snippets will help give more specific answer.