# Efax can't open serial port /dev/ttyS1: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu-mate, serial-port

Efax can not send a fax.

Socket running on port 9900
    efax-0.9a: 17:33:54 Error: can't open serial port /dev/ttyS1: Permission denied
    efax-0.9a: 17:33:54 failed page /home/andy/Documents/UHC_Appeal.pdf.001
    efax-0.9a: 17:33:54 finished - unrecoverable error

I tried most of the suggestions from here.

[Serial port terminal > Cannot open /dev/ttyS0: Permission denied](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210177/serial-port-terminal-cannot-open-dev-ttys0-permission-denied)

I had to run it as a superuser.

But the fax fails.

```
Error: no command or response from remote

Socket running on port 9900
efax-0.9a: 18:31:25 opened /dev/ttyACM0
efax-0.9a: 18:31:26 using CX93001-EIS_V0.2002-V92 in class 1
efax-0.9a: 18:31:26 dialing T1-888-517-7113
efax-0.9a: 18:31:37 connected
efax-0.9a: 18:31:39 Warning: bit-reversed HDLC frame, reversing bit order
efax-0.9a: 18:31:39 received UNKNOWN
efax-0.9a: 18:31:39 The remote ID is     Fax Server P1832
efax-0.9a: 18:31:39 received DIS - answering capabilities
efax-0.9a: 18:31:39 remote has no documents to send and can receive
efax-0.9a: 18:31:39 local   196lpi 14.4kbps 8.5"/215mm  any   1D    -     -  0ms
efax-0.9a: 18:31:39 remote  196lpi 14.4kbps 8.5"/215mm  any   2D ECM-64   -  0ms
efax-0.9a: 18:31:39 session 196lpi 14.4kbps 8.5"/215mm  any   1D    -     -  0ms
efax-0.9a: 18:31:39 sent TSI - caller ID
efax-0.9a: 18:31:40 sent DCS - session format
efax-0.9a: 18:31:44 sent TCF - channel check of 2700 bytes
efax-0.9a: 18:31:46 received CFR - channel OK
efax-0.9a: 18:31:47 header:[2019-03-16 18:31    Andrew Kennedy (0000 00000) --> 1-888-517-7113      1/1]
efax-0.9a: 18:31:56 Warning: EOF before RTC
efax-0.9a: 18:31:56 sent 20+2155 lines and 16016+0 bytes, in 9 secs at 14236 bps
efax-0.9a: 18:32:09 Error: no command or response from remote
efax-0.9a: 18:31:56 sent EOP - done
efax-0.9a: 18:32:00 received EOP - done
efax-0.9a: 18:32:00 sent EOP - done
efax-0.9a: 18:32:05 received EOP - done
efax-0.9a: 18:32:05 sent EOP - done
efax-0.9a: 18:32:09 received EOP - done
efax-0.9a: 18:32:09 sent DCN - disconnect
efax-0.9a: 18:32:11 failed page /home/andy/Documents/UHC_Appeal.pdf.001
efax-0.9a: 18:32:11 finished - invalid modem response
```

Comment: This was in my syslog. Mar 16 17:53:33 7 kernel: [17917.586578] efax-gtk[6606]: segfault at 0 ip 000055c38b19c249 sp 00007fff0708c510 error 4 in efax-gtk[55c38b12c000+b5000]

Comment: Can you share the results of `ls -alh /dev/ | grep tty`? And also the results of `groups YourUser`

Comment: @Podesta Thanks Podesta. I needed to install a DSL filter between wall jack and my USB modem.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, my advice was going to be mostly on your first problem, so you wouldn't need to run as sudo. The second part I wouldn't really be able to help, since I've never really had to work with a fax. Glad to hear you managed to figure it out.

Comment: @Podesta I found I did not need to run it as sudo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot open /dev/ttyS0: Permission denied, but in dialout group](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217871/cannot-open-dev-ttys0-permission-denied-but-in-dialout-group)